# How to make home page for website?

Tags: html

I have all the code for my website's home page as "home.html", however I want to be able for someone to just type in "example.com" and go to the "home" page instead of having to type in "example.com/home.html".  How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web servers are usually configured to serve a file with a specific name when asked for the root level of a directory. Some examples are:

- `index.htm`
- `index.html`
- `index.xml`
- `index.rxml`
- `index.asp`
- `default.asp`
- `default.aspx`
- `index.php`
- `index.cgi`
- `index.shtml`
- `iisstart.htm`

As you understand, this can vary greatly from server to server and from configuration to configuration.

So, either re-configure your web server to treat "home.html" as a valid home page, or change its name to whatever your server is configured to use.

In Apache, this is configured with the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive.

In IIS, these are called [Default document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: in addition: `default.asp` and `default.aspx` for IIS under ASP.NET

Comment: ...and "iisstart.html" - I'll update my answer with more examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Name your homepage index.html, and it will be the page your website automatically goes to when users go to `example.com`

Comment: Awesome, got it all sorted now.

Answer (score 1):

For Apache:

```
DirectoryIndex home.html index.html index.txt
```

For nginx:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /home.html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying even further!